# Is downtown an adverb of place?

Tags: grammar, nouns, prepositions, adverbs, rules

What is the explanation for why we say "I'm going downtown" instead of "I'm going to downtown?"

Comment: There you are using a noun to specify a location.  If you think that makes it an adverb, that so be it. Today I was late going downtown, but tomorrow I’ll be even later going downtowner.

Comment: Yes, *downtown* can be used adverbially. It is also listed as an adverb in various dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

"Go downtown" is similar to "go overseas", "go abroad", "go bankrupt", etc., in the sense that while it looks like a noun - and indeed it can act as one occasionally - it usually functions as an adverb.

Comment: *Bankrupt* usually functions as an adverb?  Really?

Comment: In a similar way to _bananas_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So someone who has gone grey has turned grey into an adverb then?  I don’t think they have, because *grey* refers to them, not to their going. Similarly with bankrupt.

Comment: Perhaps I'd better give up trying to be subtle.

Comment: I'd classify constructions such as go mad / crazy / bananas / grey / bankrupt as link-like structures (_go_ = turn, become, having more semantic content than _be_) with predicative adjectives. Go downtown / out / in / home / abroad / overseas employ _go_ in its primary, physical-travel sense. It is probably better to lump the directional terms as such rather than as true adverbs. This is probably wise for locatives and temporal completers also.