# What is the difference between "library downtown" and "library in downtown"?

Tags: prepositions

I was recently asked a question by my friend on the difference between:

1. I am going to the library downtown.
2. I'm going to the library in downtown.

At first, the second sentence didn't give me much sense, but I just read the sentence a couple of times, and the meaning it gave me somehow is that the first one is saying that the library is located in the **downtown area (not a specific place)**, and the second one is saying it's located in **a specific place called downtown** (like maybe a mall called downtown - FYI there is a mall called downtown in my country that's why I thought of that).

So what do you think? What is the difference?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of regional variation in how people use words like "downtown", "town", etc, lots of idioms, so this is a complex issue. This question is about "to downtown" but is relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113452/is-downtown-an-adverb-of-place

Comment: I've googled "library in downtown" (without opening links); there's only 1 distinct example in the first 20 of a non-attributive (as opposed to say 'library in downtown LA') example. But the usage _is_ out there.

Comment: We don't normally say: in downtown. We would say: in the downtown area.

Comment: @Lambie I'd say lots of _we_'s dont. But some _we_'s apparently do use this.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess it pays to be sarcastic, and just because some hits on the Internet appear does not show its common usage. You yourself said downtown LA.

Comment: It's the patronising 'we' that I'd consider out of place on ELU. There are quite a lot of examples using standalone 'in downtown'  on the internet, for instance [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22located+in+downtown+near%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&biw=1680&bih=977&ei=Fbl-YZ23DceL9u8P-PyeqAg&oq=%22located+in+downtown+near%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6CAgAEAgQBxAeSgQIQRgAUNf-Bligiwdg_6kHaAFwAngAgAFCiAHnA5IBATiYAQCgAQHIAQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjdlZCd_vTzAhXHhf0HHXi-B4UQ4dUDCA4&uact=5). It seems to be growing in acceptability.